# I need to apply for a national D visa in Italy but have no country of residence

Tags: student-visa, study, italy

I am a Brazilian citizen, however I have just completed my undergraduate degree in the UK (my visa is expiring in one week) and my parents live in Germany. I have been accepted into a masters programme in Italy starting in February and need to apply for a student visa.

My problem is that I have no proof of residency in Brazil, as I do not live there nor do I have family that I can stay with. There is no way for me to go back to Brazil at the moment.

Can I apply for an Italian student visa while staying with my parents as a tourist in Germany?

Alternatively, could I enter Italy as a tourist and then apply for a student visa from there?

Comment: You should probably apply from Germany. In the worst case you might have to register as a resident in Germany at your parents' address.

Comment: In considering whether to issue or refuse a visa, any country is very likely to wonder what will happen when the visa expires, or its terms are violated, and the visa holder has to leave the visa-issuing country. It'd be quite reasonable to refuse to issue a visa to an applicant who cannot demonstrate a right of abode in another country. I would guess that visa-issuing countries likely expect that visa applicants have that right in the country of the applicant's citizenship. Because a visa is a country's permission to *enter* that country, you're unlikely to be able to apply from within Italy.

Comment: @David that's correct, but in some cases, people can apply for *residence permits* from inside the country.  I don't know whether this would be such a case, however.

Comment: @phoog I don't dispute that. But it seems to me that a temporary admission (here, one for an academic period of time) is not likely to be available to one currently in the country. After all, the question of what happens after the visa expires or is cancelled is still unanswered, and likely to be of interest.

Comment: The Italian government visa webpage here: http://vistoperitalia.esteri.it/home/en#BMQuestionario isn't helpful on this issue.

Comment: @David well for example citizens of certain countries can get residence permits in both the Netherlands and Germany, including student residence permits.  So the intended duration of stay isn't necessarily significant.  Whether the applicant will leave at the end of the permit usually *is* significant, but in fact it is very common for students to begin a program of study without a clear idea of where they will go when they finish it, and despite that fact students get visas and permits all over the world.  I don't see why it would be a sticking point in this particular case.

Comment: @phoog I don't think we disagree. As to your last sentence...it'll only be a sticking point if it is. No one in our community here at SE seems to know. As part of its interactive "Do I Need a Visa?" page, the Italian government asks the applicant's country of residence. I'd think that Tomas By's suggestion (earlier in these comments) may well be the most sensible course of action, as overstaying in the UK won't help at all and the OP took returning to Brazil off the table.